# Does the Maypole visit humans on May the First?

Tags: european-folklore, calendar-dates

May the first has a lot of nature deity traditions like The Green Man. Then there is the Maypole. So my question is: does the Maypole visit humans on the first of May?

The Maypole may be a pole in any form, an actual ceremonial pole or something else like a child's toy pole. But whatever it is, its "visit" would involve the May pole becoming a nature-spirit element such as a faerie, serpent or elf, probably on fire; I gather that fire is also a May Day tradition.

The visit will usually occur when the human is alone and would involve some kind of message for the human. In pop culture the closest thing that I can think of is the movie Donnie Darko when Donnie meets the Rabbit.

Comment: Hi and welcome to M&F SE, please take some time to take our [Tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour). Interesting question! But I still wonder how it would look like being visited by a pole

Comment: I was careful to keep it a family show.